# Circular Polarizing filter in different lenses. Whether to use adapters or buy new filters?

Tags: lens, filters, adapter, filter-diameter

I have the following lenses
Canon 18-55 (filter ring size 58mm)
Canon 55-250 (filter ring size 58mm)
Sigma 35mm (filter ring size 67mm)
Canon 10-22 (filter ring size 77mm)
Canon 50mm (filter ring size 52mm)

I started with the first two lenses listed above and then purchased the other lenses. Most of my photography is done while travelling. I notice these days that I often only use Sigma 35mm and Canon 10-22mm for most of my photographic needs.
The issue is that the filter I own - a B+W 58mm polarizing filter, does not fit these two lenses I use most often (having 67mm and 77mm rings).

One of the ways to make it fit is through the ring adapters. However, I am not sure if it would be a good solution. Should I purchase new filters for these lenses or I can comfortably work with the ring adapters?

Your insights will really help me. Thanks in advance!
(I own a Canon T2i camera and not full frame)

Answer (score 6):

Adaptors to *reduce* the filter thread of a lens are a bad idea. They cause vignetting (dark areas in the corners). You might get away with a reduction of 2mm as different brands standardise on different sizes. Some kit lenses have bigger threads than they need so that the manufacturer needs to support fewer standard sizes. Apart from these 2 cases your not likely to have good results with step down rings.

*Step up* rings are more feasible. They're available in a wide range of sizes but not every combination.

I suggest you get a (slim) 77mm for the 10-22, and adaptor to fit this on the 67mm thread of your 35mm, and an adaptor to put the 58mm on the 50. This is the minimum you would need to buy/carry. I don't suggest stacking adaptors especially on wide angle lens, as it can worsen the problem of vignetting which some filters already have on wide angle lenses. As your widest lens is also the biggest filter, you should be OK.

Now for the downside: lens hoods. Bayonet lens hoods don't work with step up rings. Threaded lens hoods usually do (and may be worth having just for use with polarisers as these can be hard to rotate inside a hood), but will rotate with the polariser which isn't too good for wide angle lenses because the petals get in the wrong place.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that filters and step-up rings extend the edge of the lens forward and may cause vignetting at shorter focal lengths.  I have to buy slim polarizers for my wide-angle lenses, and the additional thickness of a step-up ring will negate any benefit from that.

Comment: @Blrfl good point. I'd hinted at it but not in a way that would be much help to anyone needing the answer. I've added a little bit.

Comment: Polarizers on wide-angle lenses have their own issues.  I'd ignore the 10-22 when selecting a polarizer.

Comment: @Mark assuming the 18-55 is the kit lens (and that the other lenses are better), the next lens up is the 35, which on a cropped sensor seems a little long for some things that might want a polariser. The wide end is very wide though.

Answer (score 0):

Get a [Cokin P-series filter holder](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000L47COM). The P-series works with lenses up to 82mm in thread size. You'll need an adapter ring for each thread size with which you plan to use the filter holder. Good adapter rings are available from third party sellers at [very affordable prices](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BDJ93JQ), so 77mm, 67mm, 58mm, and 52mm adapter rings will allow you to use P-series sized filters with all of your lenses.

You can then purchase the P-series sized filters you desire, either Cokin filters or cheaper [third party filters](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dphoto&field-keywords=cokin%20p-series%20filter%20kits&rh=i%3Aphoto%2Ck%3Acokin%20p-series%20filter%20kits) made to fit the Cokin P system. The round [polarizing filter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0006ZSR40) will fit in the first slot of a P-series holder. The entire holder will rotate on the adapter ring for those lenses which rotate the front element and threads when zooming or focusing.

The Cokin P-series holder will also allow the use of square and rectangular filters. This is a distinct advantage when using graduated neutral density filters. The the filter can be slid up or down in the holder to move the line of graduation to match your composition.

With an APS-C camera even your wide angle lenses should be usable with the P series, which are made to work with full frame cameras down to about 20mm focal length without any vignetting. You may have just a tad of vignetting at the wide end of the 10-22 up to about 12-13mm.

The advantage of the P-series is that it is more economical than larger systems such as the 100mm Lee system or the [100mm Cokin Z-series](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dphoto&field-keywords=cokin%20z%20series%20ring%20kits). The disadvantage of the P-series is that if you ever go to full frame you'll probably want to swap to the larger, 100mm wide Z-series or the 100mm Lee system.